# Output several times

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have the following code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

time = Time.new

url = "http://mobile.bahn.de/bin/mobil/bhftafel.exe/dox?input=Richard-Strauss-Stra%DFe%2C+M%FCnchen%23625127&date=" + 
  time.strftime("%d%m%Y") +
  "&time=" +
  time.strftime("%H") +
  "%3A" +
  time.strftime("%M") +
  "&productsFilter=1111111111000000&REQTrain_name=&maxJourneys=10&start=Suchen&boardType=Abfahrt&ao=yes"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
doc.xpath('//div//p').remove
doc.encoding = 'UTF-8'
doc = doc.xpath('//div').each do |node|
  text = node.text.gsub(/\n([ \t]*\n)+/,"\n",).gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,'').gsub("Startseite", '').gsub("Impressum", '')
  puts text unless text.empty?
end
```

I have two problems:

1. The code outputs three times and not one time.
2. The German "umlauts" like `äü`.

Answer (score 0):

The original HTML is long and not indented, so it is very hard to debug.

But I think you need to replace:

```
doc = doc.xpath('//div').each do |node|
```

With:

```
doc = doc.xpath('//body/div').each do |node|
```

The first one was also including all `<div>` elements so it included `//body/div` and then separately included the `<div>`s inside `//body/div`

I had no problems with umlaut characters, using `puts`, but did have problems writing them to a file. What is your exact problem? It might be best if you create a new question on Stack Overflow for the umlauts issue.